# Error accessing dashboard or admin interface in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch, google-app-engine-patch

I am unable to access dashboard/admin interface of Google app engine on local development environment which could be access using localhost:8000/_ah/admin/.

It throws following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2726, in _HandleRequest
      self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2611, in _Dispatch
      base_env_dict=env_dict)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 653, in Dispatch
      base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1675, in Dispatch
      self._module_dict)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1575, in ExecuteCGI
      reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1277, in ExecuteOrImportScript
      exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
      class _AhAdminXsrfToken_(db.Model):
    File "C:\Projects_2013_05_14\retail\common\appenginepatch\appenginepatcher\patch.py", line 539, in __init__
      _initialize_model(cls, bases)
    File "C:\Projects_2013_05_14\retail\common\appenginepatch\appenginepatcher\patch.py", line 523, in _initialize_model
      cls._meta = _meta(cls, bases)
    File "C:\Projects_2013_05_14\retail\common\appenginepatch\appenginepatcher\patch.py", line 246, in __init__
      raise ValueError('Django expects models (here: %s.%s) to be defined in their own apps!' % (model.__module__, model.__name__))
  ValueError: Django expects models (here: __main__._AhAdminXsrfToken_) to be defined in their own apps!
```

My development environment is as follows.
Google App Engine 1.6.1
Python 2.5
Google app engine patch for Django 1.1

I am unable to understand what is going wrong over here.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of everything? The Python 2.5 runtime is deprecated, django-apppengine-patch has been unsupported for years (use django-nonrel), the GAE SDK is on 1.8.0, and Django support is up to 1.4.

Comment: @Daniel, Its a legacy application, it might be migrated to new versions of available tools but not sure when it will happen.